Indian movie about a woman who get attacked by crocodiles
I saw this movie around 1989. A husband tries to get rid of his wife by throwing her off a boat into a crocodile-infested river. She is assumed to be dead by her husband. I think he marries another woman/mistress. However, his wife survives but is badly wounded in the face. She sells all her gold and jewelry to pay for plastic surgery. She gets a face lift and appears completely different from how she used to. She visits her son at school (without meeting him face to face).  He suspects her at first, but she puts on sunglasses to disguise herself (since he thinks his mom is dead). She does this to plan revenge on her husband.
I forgot how she commits the revenge.
What is the name of this movie? A link to IMDb would be great.

Is it an Indian film or an Asian film?  We actually have a Bollywood tag... which I know may not be appropriate but we had an Indian tag and a Bollywood tag and they decided to keep the Bollywood tag over the Indian one.

yes, @Catija it is Indian. I was not aware there was a tag indian movies.

Copy of Hollywood movie: 'Return to Eden'

Sounds like Khoon Bhari Maang from 1988, which was based on Return to Eden:

Nandini and Sanjay Verma are lovers, and they conspire to take over the vaste estate of Mr. Saxena and his only widowed daughter, Aarti, and her two children, with the help of Sanjay's maternal uncle Heeralal, a longtime employee of Saxena. After Saxena passes away suddenly, Sanjay woos Aarti and marries her. On a boating trip both Nandini and Sanjay do away with Aarti, making it look like an accident, and subsequently take over the entire Saxena estate. But Aarti survives, disfigured beyond recognition by a crocodile attack, With the help of plastic surgery transforms herself to a successful model, Jyoti. She then plans to carry out her vengeance against Sanjay, but finds that he has been physically abusing her children, pets, and servants.

Here's the scene with the crocodile attack (Warning: Bloody):




It is the film called Thendral Sudum cast by Radhika Sarath kumar
